# Admin ToolBar not being displayed at top of site

Tags: php, theme-development

Not sure what's going on, but even when I checked the "Show Toolbar when viewing site" and on functions.pho placed:

`if (! current_user_can('manage_options')) {
    add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
}`

I can see the space where the admin bar is supposed to be placed but it is empty, a white bar, nothing on it, checked the source code and found this:

`<style type="text/css" media="print">#wpadminbar { display:none; }</style>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html { margin-top: 28px !important; }
    * html body { margin-top: 28px !important; }
</style>`

So not sure what else to do, any help?

Thanks!

A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your theme does not use [`wp_footer()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer) the way it should. That function should occur right before the closing `</body>` tag. The admin bar runs on a hook fired by that function. Without it, I get exactly what you describe.

For reference, in Twenty Thirteen, it looks like this: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/footer.php

Comment: OMG, seems like I didn't see that one properly, that fixed the admin bar, thanks so much!!